# Cant set header after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I m actually trying to work with a complex function un an express route callback and I get a

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

when spamming the refresh button.

The fact is that I cant find the problem in my coffeescript file neither in the javascript file.

This is the only function that throw me out with my application, so the code executed before is not a problem (tested in fact)

Here's my coffeescript file :

```
traitementPrestationSiteAction: (idSites)->
    agency = if @qParams.agency then @qParams.agency else undefined

    if !idSites || !agency
      @response.status(400).end()
    else
      endDate = new Date()
      startDate = new Date()

      start = if @qParams.start then new Date(@qParams.start) else startDate
      end = if @qParams.end then new Date(@qParams.end) else endDate

      start.setHours(0)
      start.setMinutes(0)
      start.setSeconds(1)

      end.setHours(23)
      end.setMinutes(59)
      end.setSeconds(59)

      @TraitementNettoyage.find({'dateEntre': {$gt: start, $lte: end}, 'site': idSites, 'agency': agency},'zone objectsControlled dateEntre dateSortie')
      .populate('zone', 'zoneName')
      .populate('objectsControlled.listePrestations.prestation', '_id prestationName')
      .populate('objectsControlled.object', 'typeobjectName')
      .sort('-_id')
      .exec((err, result)=>
        if err
          @response.status(500).end()
        else
          if !result
            @response.status(204).end()
          else
            @response.send(result))
```

And the javascript associated :

```
TraitementNettoyageController.prototype.traitementPrestationSiteAction = function(idSites) {
    var agency, end, endDate, start, startDate;
    agency = this.qParams.agency ? this.qParams.agency : void 0;
    if (!idSites || !agency) {
      return this.response.status(400).end();
    } else {
      endDate = new Date();
      startDate = new Date();
      start = this.qParams.start ? new Date(this.qParams.start) : startDate;
      end = this.qParams.end ? new Date(this.qParams.end) : endDate;
      start.setHours(0);
      start.setMinutes(0);
      start.setSeconds(1);
      end.setHours(23);
      end.setMinutes(59);
      end.setSeconds(59);
      return this.TraitementNettoyage.find({
        'dateEntre': {
          $gt: start,
          $lte: end
        },
        'site': idSites,
        'agency': agency
      }, 'zone objectsControlled dateEntre dateSortie').populate('zone', 'zoneName').populate('objectsControlled.listePrestations.prestation', '_id prestationName').populate('objectsControlled.object', 'typeobjectName').sort('-_id').exec((function(_this) {
        return function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            return _this.response.status(500).end();
          } else {
            if (!result) {
              return _this.response.status(204).end();
            } else {
              return _this.response.send(result);
            }
          }
        };
      })(this));
    }
  };
```

It seems that the error is thrown in the last "else", at this line :

> return _this.response.send(result);

Can you help me ?

EDIT : @response is the standard res in express callback

EDIT 2 : I have only one made middleware and it looks like this :

```
checkFirewallMiddleware: ()->
    @User.findOne({_id: @request.user.id}).exec((err, u)=>
      if err || !u
        @response.status(500).end()
      else
        user = u.toObject()
        @request.userLoad = user
        if user.userRole is 1
          @next()
        else
          if user.userRole is 3
            onResolve = (society)=>
              @request.userLoad.society = society
              @tryNext()

            onReject = (err) =>
              if err.error == 0
                @response.status(500).end()
              else
                @response.status(204).end()

            userService = @get('UserService')
            promise = userService.getSociety(user._id)
            promise.then(onResolve, onReject)
          else
            @tryNext()
    )



  tryNext: ()->
    if @isAccessible()
      @next()
    else
      @response.status(403).end()


  isAccessible: ()->
    array = ['PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE']
    found = false
    for x in array
      if x is @request.method.toUpperCase()
        found = true
    if found
      found = false
      for a in firewallRoute
        if @request.url.match(a.freeArea) && a.verb.toUpperCase() is @request.method.toUpperCase()
          found = true
      if found
        return true
      else
        return false
    else
      return true
```

Could the problem be there ?

EDIT3 : The problems occurs when I refresh quickly the page concerned

Comment: The code before might not raise an error, but could still be the source of the problem. If you for instance would try to send a response in the previous code and then try to send it again from here.

Comment: Nothing is sent before this. If I comment this fully function, everything is working great :-/